# I turned on Source Tracking and then refreshed my sandbox, but it's still not enabled

Tags: salesforcedx, sandbox-refresh

I have a dev pro sandbox I use. Source Tracking was not enabled, so I enabled it in the prod org.

I read that new and refreshed dev and dev pro sandboxes will now have Source Tracking enabled.

So, I refreshed an unused dev pro sandbox with my sandbox, and then refreshed my sandbox with that other sandbox.

Still, when I execute sfdx force:source:push, I get a message telling me that only works on orgs which have source tracking enabled. (BTW, I did reload my VS Code window.)

Why is Source Tracking not yet enabled in my sandbox?

Comment: Did you try turning it on on the sandbox directly (or is this not allowed)? I expect the setting is copied from the original org into the new sandbox. Here the original org is your existing sandbox by the sound of it.

Comment: I think it can only be enabled in the Production org. I suspect that the setting is only copied to newly-created sandboxes and those which are refreshed from Prod. But, if this is so, the instructions should state this more clearly. (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_setup_enable_source_tracking_sandboxes.htm)

Answer (score 0):

As of this date, if you refresh the sandbox from the old sandbox (where source tracking is not enabled), your new sandbox is also not enabled for source tracking. This limitation sucks, especially if you were to switch over to the DevOps center or things like that